# Не показывается карта в модальном окне

Tags: google-maps-api

В такой блоке лежит ( или должна лежать г-карта )

```
<div class="modal-body" style="width:1000px;"> 
   <div id="map-canvas"/></div>
</div>
```

При открытии окна виден только серый фон, НО , когда происходит ресайз окна видна карта + если креплю карту куда-то не в модальное окно - то она видна.Если честно без понятия почему так, может кто сталкивался - подскажите как исправить

js на всякий случай

```
( function(window, google) {

    var options = {
        center:{
            lat:37,
            lng:37
        },
        zoom:10
    }

    element = document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
    map = new google.maps.Map(element,options);

} (window, google))
```

Answer (score 1):

добавление ресайза всё исправило + впихнул получение мапы в отдельный метод который срабатывает при клике на кнопку, которая выдает модальное окно

```
function resizeMap() {
       if(typeof map =="undefined") return;
       setTimeout( function(){resizingMap();} , 400);
    }

    function resizingMap() {
       if(typeof map =="undefined") return;
       var center = map.getCenter();
       google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
       map.setCenter(center);
    }
```